# Get device parameters from appium automatically

Tags: java, android, mobile, appium, udid

I have one little question. 
Can I get device parameters like UDID from appium when it's session is starting and pass it to my pom.xml?
And if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in run-time:

```
    driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("udid")
```